# Monitorar os eventos da JRE

Tags: java, eclipse, log, log4j

Tem como monitorar alguns eventos da jre como start, close etc?
existem bibliotecas para isso?
Preciso criar um log para armazenar a hora que a jre é acionada, fechada e saber quem acessou, tudo isso deverá ficar dentro de um arquivo txt na máquina local, existe algum material que eu possa usar para referência ou alguma biblioteca específica que faça isso?

Comment: Existem várias possibilidades para monitorar um processo, ainda que não seja especificamente a JRE. A melhor abordagem depende do contexto. Teria como você dizer um pouco sobre o problema que você quer resolver?

Comment: É uma proposta de sistema em que tenho que controlar os eventos em um log texto, start, close, erro, etc. Estou pesquisando a viabilidade e qual tecnologia seria melhor para desenvolver.

Comment: Para mim continua vago o conceito de "monitorar" e pra que exatamente você preciso disso. Digo isso porque monitorar a JRE pode não ser a melhor forma, talvez monitorar a aplicação executando dentro da máquina virtual seja mais adequado. É uma aplicação desktop ou web? Se for apenas monitorar quando o programa roda ou não, basta criar um script que grava num log antes ou depois de executar o Java. Ou seria possível ainda criar um programa que verifica a cada N segundos se o processo do Java está sendo executado ou não. É esse tipo de coisa que você precisa?

Comment: Se for uma aplicação web você pode criar um web service de diagnóstico e consultar esse serviço em determinados períodos.